# Prepping graphics to make silk screen for pottery

Tags: adobe-illustrator, screen-printing

First time posting here. Lovely to meet you all!

I'm wanting to learn how to take a graphic I find online, say of a comic character, and do whatever I need to do to it to end up with a single colour silk screen mesh. The mesh will later be used with a kind of clay paint (underglaze) on rice paper to make transfers, so I assume it will be a large-hole mesh that I need to use.

Can people please point me to tutorials etc that I can learn from? and perhaps also suggest PC programs I can use aside from Illustrator?
I've used photoshop to some small extent in the past, so looking to learn the jargon ect.

Essentially I need to prepare the art work to make the screen (I'm having someone else make the screen for me, but not do any printing). I'm hoping to have a number (10-20) small images done on the screen, kinda like a stencile set.

I'm just needing to know where to start. Thank you all so much!!
As an example, how do I get something like the first image into something like the last image? Is there even a name for such a process?

[image] [image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use Illustrator?

Comment: I simply don't have it at this point. My life is sad. Also.. I've never used it. I intend for both of those things to change. I just can't afford it now.

Answer (score 1):

You really **don't** get *"the first image into something like the second image"*.

While there may be some steps to reduce color and add contrast to images such as your first example, **nothing** will ultimately end up looking like solid line art, like your second example. It's a complete myth that you can create line art from a painting. You can't. You can merely create a less detailed painting from a painting.

If you need solid line art, the only real choice is to **draw it**. You can do this in *any* software which allows you to draw. Or even on a piece of paper with a pen. Converting a solid *drawing* to screen-print-ready art isn't an issue. The problem you'll face here is trying to convert a *painting* to *line art*.

That being posted, a painting with solid, flat coloring *may* offer some ability to merely remove colors and tweak levels to intensify an *existing* outline.

For example... relatively flat color like this:

[image]
<sub>Source: [Dribble - Peter Quill](https://dribbble.com/shots/2348885-Guardians-Of-The-Galaxy-2014-Star-Lord-Peter-Quill)</sub>

..... can be refined to keep only the black key line.

However, to try and accomplish the same thing with a full-on, digital painting, like your first example, is a no-win situation. It can't be done with any automated processes or setting adjustments.

Software can do a lot these days, however it can't do everything. You still need some manual artistic skill to accomplish some tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get something like the first image into something like the last image? Is there even a name for such a process?

Yeap, the name for this is: **Draw it again**.

The second image has a totally different style.

You could try some things like converting the image to CMYK and then contrast it a lot the black channel but it will not work on this image. You need to draw it in Ilustrator.

[image]

**Other programs besides Ilustrator?**

The Options are Corel Draw, Afinity Designer and Inkscape.

Comment: If you took Rafaels black and white result into illustrator, traced it, expanded, ungrouped and United you would then have solid black and white shapes that can be manipulated into 1 color art for glazing.  Drawing new borders, filling in missing pieces and playing with stroke thickness is some of the manipulation you'd need to make it look good.